# JAX-RS i want to know the endpoint to begin

Tags: jax-rs

i am a complete beginner in java world, i want to start building an JAX-RS endpoint so i am using Intellij with glassfish/tomcat application servers.

after i run my server, i tried all the urls like

- http://localhost:8080/Demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT/api/hello-world
- http://localhost:8080/Demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT/hello-world

and it didn't work.also i tried with tomcat, same problem. it would be nice if someone help me unblock this problem.

here is my project and its configuration :

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOalD.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj8KI.png

Answer (score -1):

I think you need a web.xml under src/main/webapp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            15
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

And you can put the beans.xml in the same Folder.

Comment: i put the beans.xml and web.xml in the webapp folder but still it's not working

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/sOMF6gH.png